# Is there a performance hit for using EXTERNAL working storage variables

Tags: cobol, mainframe

This question is regarding IBM Enterprise COBOL 4.2.

I have a program that requires a change and an increase to a working storage buffer. Unfortunately, this increase in buffer size has put me over the 128M max for the working storage section. My plan was to take some of the bigger `01` variables and make them `EXTERNAL`, but I am concerned that this will impact system performance.

Does anyone know if making working storage variables external will slow down system performance?

I have been told that in about a year we will be switching to COBOL 6.1, so if it is a small performance decrease, we should be able to handle it until we get 6.1 (where the working storage limits have been increased to 2G)

Comment: I think External is for sharing data across different programs but I don't believe it changes the 128M limit on 4.2.  I'd need to experiment but while I look at that, perhaps it would be easier to use Linkage and use a sub-program to allocate storage that linkage can point to as an alternative ?

Comment: @Hogstrom There is 128 for working storage and an additional 128 for external. I just don't know how it will affect performance.

Comment: One thing is that this does is increase register pressure. Each Level 1 data item will be pointed to by a BLX pointer. It does seem like COBOL v4.2 tries to keep the loaded BLX value in a register, but I think its possible that you will see more L instructions for BLX addresses. A way to minimize this would be to minimize the number of EXTERNAL level 1 data items you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a practical matter, using `EXTERNAL` is no different than the system calling a program with each external data item as if it were a linkage section data item. I suggest compiling a small program and examining the generated code to see what the differences are.

```
working-storage section.
01 ws-data pic x(8).
01 ext-data pic x(8) external.
linkage section.
01 ls-data pic x(8).
procedure division using ls-data.
begin.
    move spaces to ws-data
    move spaces tp ext-data
    move spaces to ls-data
    goback
    .
```

I suspect there is no difference between accessing `ext-data` and `ls-data`.

This would provide specific information on how much of a "hit" to expect.

Comment: When you say generated code, do you mean looking at the assembly, or looking for added code (similar to what a DB2 pre-compiler does with DB2 statements or CICS commands).

Comment: @SaggingRufus - Assembly.

Comment: Do you know what compiler option will generate that? Unfortunately, I haven't had to generate the assembly for anything before.

Comment: @SaggingRufus - No, haven't used it in a few decades!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll see if I can get the assembly

Comment: @SaggingRufus - Seems it is `LIST`. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ui/up2030.htm

Comment: There were a couple is extra load instructions when displaying and initializing, but the moves were identical

Answer (score 2):

There is extra checking involved (and name lookup involved) in locating the EXTERNAL data item.  This processing is done once per 01 level EXTERNAL data item defined in each program, when the program starts up.  There is also extra memory management overhead for EXTERNAL data item (as compared to working-storage defined data item.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you used your maximum `WORKING-STORAGE` (128 Mb) and you need more, you'll have to use the `EXTERNAL` space. Whether it impacts the performance or not, you'll need it anyways. It may slow down your performance (because the compiler needs to load more data), but that latency is negligible.

Second of all, compile your program with the `OPTIMIZE(FULL)` option, this will list all unused variables in your program (and I bet u will find some). This can save some space and it's much cleaner code.

Hope this helps.